# Is it possible to create joining lines in GUI?

Tags: oop, user-interface, matlab, drag

To put it bluntly, I need to create extensible lines in my GUI that can be made to link two 'static text' or 'edit text' boxes together (there are probably other programs that do this better but MATLAB is a must in this case). If the lines can be bent and otherwise edited, it's a bonus. Is there a way to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it depends a bit on the exact features you need. For any solution, you need to draw axes encompassing the area where you'd like to have your line, and then you can use e.g. [IMLINE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imline.html) to draw a draggable, moveable line ([IMPOLY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/impoly.html) will give you the possibility to have lines with multiple points).

For example

```
fh = figure
ah = axes('parent',fh,'units','normalized','position',[0 0 1 1],...
    'color','none','xtick',[],'ytick',[],'xlim',[0 1],'ylim',[0 1])
uicontrol('parent',fh,'units','normalized','position',...
    [0.1,0.5,0.1,0.1],'style','edit','string','A')
uicontrol('parent',fh,'units','normalized','position',...
    [0.8,0.5,0.1,0.1],'style','edit','string','B')
h = imline(ah)
```

[image]